# Find jars in a jar

Tags: java, jar, packaging

Suppose I have a jar file named test.jar. I am assigned the task to list all jars that are packed in this test.jar.

The catch is that whoever packed this test.jar, packed it in away that it doesn't show-up jars in the output of the below command, rather it's just a list of .class files and package structures.

```
jar -tvf test.jar
```

Any pointer in that direction please..

Comment: Which is just like a normal .jar looks like - although you pack jars in jar, there is usually no point in that.

Comment: @Gyro..if you export a project in eclipse..It asks you which contents and how you want to export.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is Linux, you can try the **unzip** command:

```
unzip -l your_jar_file.jar
```

From Java you can also list the jar file contents. It must be something like this:

```
ZipFile jarFile = new ZipFile( jarFilePath );
Enumeration<? extends ZipEntry> entries = jarFile.entries();
while( entries.hasMoreElements() ) {
    System.out.println( entries.nextElement().getName() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But I am not looking to do this in Java..rather anyhow..I want extract those jar files. If you export in eclipse it lets you choose what contents and how you want to pack in jar. If someone didn't chose it correctly while packing jars in a jar. you will not able to unpack those nested jars.

Answer (score 1):

To do this from within java, instantiate a ZipFile using the filename.  The ZipFile has a method, `entries()`, which returns an Enumerator over all of the ZipEntries in the ZipFile (members in the jar).  You can iterate using the enumerator and ask each entry for its name.  List just those entries whose names end in ".jar"

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. But I am not looking to do this in Java..rather anyhow..I want extract those jar files. If you export in eclipse it lets you choose what contents and how you want to pack in jar. If someone didn't chose it correctly while packing jars in a jar. you will not able to unpack those nested jars.